# What kind of calculations do I have to make for projectiles?

Tags: 2d, projectile-physics

I could never find out, how to create projectiles in a 2D game. Does it need linear algebra? If not, what to do to calculate its path?

I just simply want to create a projectile that follows a straight line, for every possible angles (0-359) in general. Later I want to create parabole or circular trajectories if I can.

Comment: You can get away with a simple understanding of vectors. Scaling a vector, adding two vectors together, subtracting two vectors from one another.

Comment: This is like asking "what type of dough should I use?". It really depends on what you are making. How do you want your bullets to move? Do you want them to have drop? Do you want them to follow the mouse? Please be a little more specific.

Comment: @AidanMueller Why projectiles should follow the mouse? A projectile has to be shot out to hit something.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt They would follow the mouse if you wanted something like a guided rocket. It was just an example. This question is just a little vague. There isn't really a correct way of making a projectile. It could be as simple as increasing or decreasing the X position depending on the direction it is facing. Or it could be very complicated, and take into account things like air resistance, gravity, and even the earths rotation (in real life, bullets are affected by the earths rotation if you're shooting east or west). Please tell us what you need.

Comment: @AidanMueller In fact, you are right, I just didn't get this only example. I just simply want to create a projectile that follows a straight line, for every possible angles (0-359) in general. Later I want to create parabole or circular trajectories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculating the trajectory of a projectile can be done in two ways: analytically and numerically.

Analytical calculation is where you integrate position with respect to time and get equations such as `x = x_0 + vt + ½at^2`.  You can use these equations to solve for time of impact, distance traveled, maximum height, etc. or just find the displacement at any given time.

Numerical calculation is much better suited for games.  Your standard simple little physics simulation using Euler is an example of a numerical integrator:

```
a.y = -9.81;
v += a * dt;
x += v * dt;
```

Normally, this combined with a collision detection system is all a game would need to simulate a projectile.  It works well because arbitrary input can be provided and the system will automatically correct itself without having to change the math like an analytical solution would.

---

To "launch" a projectile at a certain direction and speed, you can calculate the velocity like this (assuming direction is in radians):

```
v.x = cos(direction) * speed;
v.y = sin(direction) * speed;
```

Answer (score 1):

A direction vector and speed is all you need to begin with.